# Finding all eigenvalues of a bounded strictly upper triangle operator in a Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, infinite-matrices

I've been working on this question for awhile, and am not sure how to finish the argument. It feels like I'm on the right track though. I've demonstrated my approach below:

**Question:** Let $E$ be a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$. Let $T:E \to E$ be a bounded, linear, strictly upper triangular operator with respect to $\{e_i\},$ i.e. $\left< Te_j,e_i \right> = 0$ if $i \leq j$. Find all eigenvalues of $T$.

**My Current Approach:** Let $x \in E,$ be a unit eigenvector for $T$. Then

$$\lambda \left<x, x\right> = \left<Tx, x\right> = \left<\sum_j \alpha_j T e_j, x\right> $$ 
$$ = \sum_j \alpha_j \left<T e_j, x\right> $$
$$ = \sum_j \alpha_j \sum_i \bar{\alpha_i} \left<T e_j, e_i\right> $$
$$ = \sum_j \sum_{i > j} \alpha_j \bar{\alpha_i} \left<T e_j, e_i\right> $$

My intuition tells me that either all of the eigenvalues will be equal to zero, or there will be no eigenvalue eigenvector pairs at all. In my attempt, I'm trying to show that the right hand side reduces to zero, proving that $\lambda = 0.$

Comment: As far as I'm aware this is a highly non-trivial question and I don't know of any general statement about this. For example take the left shift on $\ell_2(\mathbb N)$ with respect to the standard basis - the matrix representation is 1 right above the diagonal and 0 everywhere else thus strictly upper triangular. So although its diagonal elements are all zero, the point spectrum (eigenvalues) of the left shift is the whole open unit disk of $\mathbb C$. You see the diagonals of a bounded strictly upper tr. operator don't even have to be dense in its point spectrum (let alone the whole spectrum)